# unable to convert text file into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to convert a text file into a dictionary 
sample text file is

```
{'name': 'sk', 'confirm': 'sk', 'passwd': 'sk', 'phone': 'sk', 'uname': 'sk', 'email': 'sk'}
{'name': 'skak', 'confirm': 'ak', 'passwd': 'ak', 'phone': 'ak', 'uname': 'ak', 'email': 'ak'}
```

and 
as i am using code

```
d = dict((line.strip().split(' = ') for line in file('raw_data'))) 
print(d)
```

and i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
d = dict((line.strip().split(' = ') for line in file('raw_data')))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

please help me to solve this error

Comment: Why are you trying to split by `=` when your file contents are in a form of a regular Python dictionary? Try parsing the lines with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead.

Comment: Is this data JSON? There is a module for parsing JSON.

Comment: no this is python data

Comment: @BryanOakley - JSON standard requires double quotes, not single ones. The posted data is the most similar to a Python `dict`.

Comment: @zwer: good point.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve this with ast.literal_eval()

Comment: @ShikharGupta have you read the docs for `ast#literal_eval`? Also please keep in mind that there are inherent risks in using `eval`-derived functions in almost any language.

Answer (score 0):

Becareful evaling a data file. Do not do this if you don't have complete control and confidence in the text file:

```
with open('datafile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        d = eval(line)
        print d
```

outputs:

```
{'name': 'sk', 'uname': 'sk', 'passwd': 'sk', 'confirm': 'sk', 'phone': 'sk', 'email': 'sk'}
{'name': 'skak', 'confirm': 'ak', 'passwd': 'ak', 'phone': 'ak', 'uname': 'ak', 'email': 'ak'}
```

It would be much safer to replace the single quotes to double and read as json.

```
import json
d = json.loads(line.replace("'", '"'))
```